# Getting a Tensor Shape (None, 128, 80) Instead of Expected (Batch_Size, 128, 80) When Fitting in Keras

Tags: keras, tf.keras

I'm facing an issue during model fitting in Keras where the shape of my input tensor is being displayed as (None, 128, 80) instead of the expected shape of (Batch_Size, 128, 80). The None value, which is supposed to be automatically replaced with the actual batch size is not getting updated. How can I ensure that the batch size is correctly applied to the tensor shape during the fitting process.

I check the shape of the input tensor by calling `model.get_layer('model_input').output` and the output is `KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 128, 80), dtype=tf.float32, name='model_input'), name='model_input', description="created by layer 'model_input'")`